# Live jQuery Thumbnails with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to implement the jQuery live thumbnails with my PHP page. On the page I am retrieving event information along with a comma separated list of thumbnail values. The plugin works a bit differently that that and I am having difficulty adapting my script to work. The plugin is located here http://tutorialzine.com/2012/12/album-photo-previews-jquery/. In their example they use an array while I have a comma separated list of thumbnails. The code I have so far is here...

```
<?php foreach ($events as $event) { ?>
    <div class="left13 section_home" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        <h2><?php echo $event['event_title']; ?></h2>
        <div align="center">
            <?php foreach ($event['thumbnails'] as $thumbnail) { ?>
                <a href="#" data-images="<?php echo str_replace(',', '|', $event['thumbnails']); ?>" class="album">
                <img src="<?php echo ($event['thumbnails'] != '') ? base_url() . 'media/photos/thumbnail/' . $event['thumbnails'] : base_url() . 'images/no_photo_thumbnail.png'; ?>" alt="" title="" /><span class="preloader"></span></a>
                <p><?php echo ($event['event_description'] != '') ? substr($event['event_description'], 0, 200) : 'No description yet...'; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/events/view/<?php echo $event['event_id']; ?>" class="section_more"><span class="swirl_left"><span class="swirl_right">View This Event</span></span></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

How would I be able to make this script work by using a comma separated list of thumbnail values instead of the array used in the tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error in console (F12)?

Comment: No, there are no errors when I check the console.

Comment: Why not convert your comma separated list into an array?

Comment: Also, I think in your thumbnails loop you want to use `$thumbnail` versus `$event['thumbnails']`, yes? Not sure what would be the point of the loop otherwise...

Comment: I converted the thumbnails to an array, but my array is different than in the example. My array looks like Array([0] => Ferrari-458-Italia-01_thumb.jpg [1] => ferrari_458_02_thumb.jpg [2] => Ferrari_458_Italia-01_thumb.jpg [3] => ferrarif430italia_lead_thumb.jpg), where as the example is a multidimensional one. Is it even possible to integrate this into my script?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and the answer is quite simple. First, my data coming from the database included a comma separated list of thumbnails. I just used the proper functions to insert that data into the script. The only problem I have now is that I need to add the path to the beginning of each value in the comma separated list. Is there a PHP function to do that? Below is my almost finished code.

```
<div class="content">
    <?php foreach ($events as $event) {
        // Create an array out of the comma separated list of thumbnails 
        $thumbnails = explode(',', $event['thumbnails']); ?>
        <div class="left13 section_home" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            <h2><?php echo $event['event_title']; ?></h2>
            <div align="center">
                <a href="#" data-images="<?php echo str_replace(',', '|', $event['thumbnails']); ?>" class="album"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'media/photos/thumbnail/' . $thumbnails[0]; ?>" alt="" title="" /><span class="preloader"></span></a>
                <p><?php echo ($event['event_description'] != '') ? substr($event['event_description'], 0, 200) : 'No description yet...'; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/events/view/<?php echo $event['event_id']; ?>" class="section_more"><span class="swirl_left"><span class="swirl_right">View This Event</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

To finish this up I need to add the following to the beginning of each item in $event['thumbnails']...

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/photos/thumbnail/
```

Then it should work perfectly.